# which log file on ubuntu server is responsible for logging why network interface failed to up during boot?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-9.04, network-adapter, logging

Was playing with tftp and screwed up something in boot sequence. Eth2 fails to start at boot but allows to be restarted manually. Can not find error message in logs... so, which log file on ubuntu server would show why network interface (eth2) failed to up during boot process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/var/log/dmesg` contains diagnostic information on what happened during the last boot-up and initialisation of the system. You may find what you are looking for there. You could also use the `dmesg` command to quickly look through the dmesg log.

Comment: I've checked dmesg and syslog - nothing there...